# Angular ngClick: only works in some cases

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm trying to override an `<a>` link with ng-click, but it only works when I have loaded the page using the base URL.

I realise this sounds weird, but you can see the consequence by comparing http://afmnew.herokuapp.com/ with http://afmnew.herokuapp.com/criteria/price/1 and using the buttons on the right to apply filters. In the latter case you will see the map flashes as it reloads, whereas in the former is simply deletes and adds the markers.

This is the key pieces of code, stating with the HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified price">
    <a href="criteria/price/1" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="main.applyFilter($event)">Budget</a>
    <a href="criteria/price/2" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="main.applyFilter($event)">Mid-range</a>
    <a href="criteria/price/3" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="main.applyFilter($event)">Fine dining</a>
</div>
```

This is the relevant function in my controller. The controller definitely gets loaded when I use the longer URL as this controller processes the URL to apply the relevant filter. I don't know where to begin trying to track down the problem now.

```
angular.module 'afmnewApp'
.controller 'MainCtrl', (Restos, $stateParams, $state, Dictionary) ->

    this.reset = () ->
        console.log "MainCtrl: reset"
        this.data.offcanvas = false
        Restos.reset()

    apply = (q, v) ->
        Restos.data.headTitle = "The Amsterdam Foodie's top "+Restos.data.pageTitle
        Restos.data.metaDescription = "The Amsterdam Foodie's top "+Restos.data.pageTitle
        if v == 'price'
            Restos.data.pageTitle = Dictionary.prices[q-1].name + " "+ Dictionary.prices[q-1].suffix
            Restos.priceFilter parseInt q
        else
            Restos.data.pageTitle = Dictionary.cuisines[q].name + Dictionary.cuisines[q].suffix
            Restos.cuisineFilter q  

    this.applyFilter = (event) ->
        console.log event.target.href
        event.preventDefault()
        params = event.target.href.match(/criteria\/(.*)\/(.*)$/)
        console.log("MainCtrl: applyFilter: ", params) if Restos.debug
        this.data.offcanvas = false
        # $state.transitionTo 'criteria', {criteria:params[1], q:params[2]}, {inherit:false}
        # stateObj =
        #    criteria: params[1]
        # history.pushState({}, "null", "criteria/"+params[1]+"/"+params[2]);
        apply params[2], params[1]

    this.data = Restos.data     # needed to pass click from navbar
    # preparePage = () ->
    console.log "MainCtrl: loading..."
    # Restos.data.offcanvas = false
    # This code causes the problem
    if $stateParams.criteria
        q = $stateParams.q
        ga 'send', 'pageview', '/'+$stateParams.criteria+'/' + q
        # Restos.data.intro = false
        # console.log "mainCtrl: Criteria type %s, value %s", $stateParams.criteria, q if Restos.debug
        apply $stateParams.q, $stateParams.criteria
    else
        ga 'send', 'pageview', '/'
        Restos.data.pageTitle = "Restaurant recommendations"
        Restos.data.headTitle = "Restaurant recommendations by the Amsterdam Foodie"
        Restos.data.metaDescription = "The Amsterdam Foodie's top restaurant recommendations from among 400 reviews"
        # default filter is applied anyway
```

Comment: Both linked examples seem to be working the same way, as far as I can see.

Comment: @hon2a if you look at the map, you will see that there is a flicker in the second instance as the whole view refreshes. In the first, the markers are removed and new ones added without refreshing the map. I've since discovered that it has something to do with the ui.router, so this question is misplaced

Answer (score 0):

Try `event` instead of `$event`:

```
 angular.module('afmnewApp').controller('MainCtrl', function() {
    this.applyFilter = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // change model and thus view...
    };
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, but it did not fix it